# How to add data to Json response in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, postgresql

am using 2 databases in my project mongodb and postgresql. i have to attach the data which is stored in pg to the Json data return from mongodb based on userid so please help me here.

expected result :

```
{
"previous": [
    {
      "_id": "591453340a59301b9471e3d1",
      "university_id": "7",
      "email": "time@time.com",
      "total_hours": "02:00",
      "universityName":"AAAAA"
    },
     "previous": [
    {
      "_id": "591453340a59301b9471e3d1",
      "university_id": "6",
      "email": "time@time.com",
      "total_hours": "02:00",
      "universityName":"CCCC"
    }
    ]
}
```

`_id`,`university_id`,`email`& `total_hours` are from mongo and `universityName` from PG

from my code 
-getting mongo json data and universityName separately(`university_id` is common in both data) but not getting how to combine these to based on `university_id`

here is my code

```
entries.find({
        "email": data.email,
    }).toArray().then(function(result) {
        result.map(function(t){
            db.query('select * from universities where _id =$1', [t.university_id],function(err,univers){
                if (err) return callback(new Error('error'));
                result.universityName = univers.rows[0].universityName
                  return callback(null, result);
            })
        })

    }).catch(function(err) {
        return callback(new Error(err));
    })


Mongodb database 

{
      "_id": "591453340a59301b9471e3d1",
      "university_id": "7",
      "email": "time@time.com",
      "total_hours": "02:00" 
    }

Postgresql:

_id |  universityName
1   |  aaaa
6   | bbbb
7   | vvvv
```

Comment: A JavaScript object cannot have "two" keys as the same name, so your output format is invalid. Also how are we to know what the data looks like in the response from each database based on the information present in your question? How about simply showing each response and asking how to put them together, if that is your actual question.

Comment: @NeilLunn i have added my mongo and pg table structure `_id` in university table is know as `university_id` in mongo collection. can please tel me how to show each response then putting them together

Comment: Are you seriously expecting someone to try and reproduce your specific scenario? If you asked a Mongo question, then people have that setup and can answer you. If you have a postgresql question, then other people have that setup and can answer you. How many people do you think are really out there with an environment using both? Like I said earlier but you seem to have difficulty understanding. Simply provide us with the "JavaScript Object Ouput" of each database request. Then your question is really just about "JavaScript". And **lots** of people can answer that question. How to ask.